# How to convert date time in to required date format in angular date pipe?

Tags: angular, datetime, date-pipe

I am using angular 8. I want to convert this date time format ("17/06/2020 10:01:09") in to this format ("17/06/2020"). But i can't resolve this issue. I am getting this error "InvalidPipeArgument: 'Unable to convert "17/06/2020 10:01:09" into a date' for pipe 'DatePipe'".

//html

```
<p>My date: {{myDate | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</p>
```

//ts file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
   myDate = '17/06/2020 10:01:09';
}
```

Please help to find me a solution. thanks.

Comment: can't you just use substr(0,10)?

Comment: your date string is not supported / not a valid date. you can use moment or use a string that is compatible with new date()

Comment: Your date string format is invalid, quickest fix is switch month with day: `06/17/2020...` (MM/DD/YY is a standard format, not DD/MM/YY)

Answer (score 1):

angular Date pipe works on Date object not on a string;

```
myDate = new Date();
```

and then your pipe works fine;

Comment: It does support a string provided it's in the right format accepted by JS `Date`

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xmujny?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html